# How to logout G+ plus sigin from different Activity?

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I have implemented his code working on successfully on the same activity, but how can I log out from another Activity.

To refer full code: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

```
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on second activity create

```
public GoogleActivity google_activity;
```

on Google Activity initialize

```
SecondActivity.google_activity=this;
```

Then you can call

```
google_activity.signout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in one of my project...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  


        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();   

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);   

    }  

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.signout) {
            //DialogUtils.getInstance().
            signOut();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void signOut() {        

        // Google sign out
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                       startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```